# Apache Ignite - move data from one server to another

Tags: caching, server, cluster-computing, ignite

I have Ignite instance started as a 'server mode' on computer A, created cache in it and stored 1M Key->Values inside the cache.

Then I started Ignite instance as a 'server mode' on computer B which joined Ignite instance on computer A and now have a cluster of 2 nodes.

Is it possible to move all 1M K->V from computer A to computer B (without any interruption for querying data or ingesting data) so that computer A can be shut down for maintenance and everything continue to work from computer B?

If this is possible - what are the steps and code to do that (move data from A -> B)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignite distributes data across server nodes according to [Cache Modes](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-modes).

In `REPLICATED` mode each server holds a copy of all data, so you can shut down any node and data won't be lost.

In `PARTITIONED` mode you can set `CacheConfiguration.backups` to `1` (or more) so that data is evenly distributed across server nodes, but each server also holds a copy of data from some other server. In this scenario you can shut down any single node and data won't be lost.

Answer (score 1):

There are the features named "backup" and "CacheRebalanceMode" of IgniteCache.I think you can try these.